# box stacking algorithm , each box used once

Tags: python, data-structures

Given a group of boxes. I want arrange the boxes on top of each other to reach the maximum height. box cannot be placed on top of another box unless the area of 2D base is <=  the 2D base of the lower box.   allowed to rotated any box to use any two sides as its base.

For example, consider below 4 boxes where each box has the following dimensions

Input: Box 1: (4,5,2), Box 2:(3,1,6), Box 3:(3,2,1), Box 4:(6,8,3)

Output: From bottom to top as follows:
Box 4 on the base (6,3) and height 8,
then Box 1 on the base (4,2) and height 5,
then Box 2 on the base (1,3) and height 6,
finally, on top Box 3 on the base (2,1) and height 3.
The total height is 22

this solution is work but use all instances of all boxes but i need use only one instance for each box.

this code get the same height but use the box 2 twice and ignore another box

the problem is in if statement in this 2 for loop

```
>  for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(0, i):
        if (rot[i].w <= rot[j].w and rot[i].l <= rot[j].l) and rot[i].boxNo != rot[j].boxNo:
            if msh[i] < msh[j] + rot[i].h:
                msh[i] = msh[j] + rot[i].h
```

how to prevent using the same box twice?

```
class Box:
def __init__(self,l, w, h):
    self.h = h
    self.w = w
    self.l = l
    self.boxNo = 0
def __lt__(self,other):
    return self.l * self.w < other.l * other.w
```

def maxStackHeight(arr, n):

```
# Create an array of all rotations of given boxes.
rot = [Box(0, 0, 0) for _ in range(3 * n)]

index = 0
no=1
for i in range(n):
    # original box
    rot[index].h = arr[i].h
    rot[index].l = max(arr[i].l, arr[i].w)
    rot[index].w = min(arr[i].l, arr[i].w)
    rot[index].boxNo=no

    index = index+ 1
    # First rotation
    rot[index].h = arr[i].w
    rot[index].l = max(arr[i].h, arr[i].l)
    rot[index].w = min(arr[i].h, arr[i].l)
    rot[index].boxNo = no
    index = index + 1

    # Second rotation
    rot[index].h = arr[i].l
    rot[index].l = max(arr[i].h, arr[i].w)
    rot[index].w = min(arr[i].h, arr[i].w)
    rot[index].boxNo = no
    index = index + 1
    no=no+1

n=n*3 # new number of boxes
rot.sort(reverse=True) #Sort array in descending order of base area

msh = [0] * n

for i in range(n):
    msh[i] = rot[i].h

# Compute optimized msh values in bottom up manner
for i in range(1, n):
    for j in range(0, i):
        if (rot[i].w <= rot[j].w and rot[i].l <= rot[j].l) and rot[i].boxNo != rot[j].boxNo:
            if msh[i] < msh[j] + rot[i].h:
                msh[i] = msh[j] + rot[i].h

maxm = -1
for i in range(n):
    maxm = max(maxm, msh[i])
return maxm

arr = [Box(4,5,2),Box(3,1,6),Box(3,2,1),Box(6,8,3)]
n = len(arr)
print("The maximum possible height of stack is",maxStackHeight(arr, n))
```

Comment: Could you give each box a unique box ID, and when finding your final solution, ensure that box ID occurs only once?

Comment: yes each box gived boxNo but the if statement not work correctly

Comment: sorry, I must've missed that. See my answer below for some working code that gets the answer you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do the trick, it uses itertools module to create every possible combination of the boxes using cartesian product, and only checks ones that meet the criteria for your problem.

```
from itertools import product

class Box:
    def __init__(self,l, w, h):
        self.h = h
        self.w = w
        self.l = l
        self.boxNo = 0

    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.l * self.w < other.l * other.w

def maxStackHeight(arr, n):
    # Create an array of all rotations of given boxes.
    rot = [Box(0, 0, 0) for _ in range(3 * n)]
    numBoxes = n

    index = 0
    no=1
    for i in range(n):
        # original box
        rot[index].h = arr[i].h
        rot[index].l = max(arr[i].l, arr[i].w)
        rot[index].w = min(arr[i].l, arr[i].w)
        rot[index].boxNo=no

        index = index+ 1
        # First rotation
        rot[index].h = arr[i].w
        rot[index].l = max(arr[i].h, arr[i].l)
        rot[index].w = min(arr[i].h, arr[i].l)
        rot[index].boxNo = no
        index = index + 1

        # Second rotation
        rot[index].h = arr[i].l
        rot[index].l = max(arr[i].h, arr[i].w)
        rot[index].w = min(arr[i].h, arr[i].w)
        rot[index].boxNo = no
        index = index + 1
        no=no+1

    rot.sort(reverse=True) #Sort array in descending order of base area

    # Compute optimized msh values in bottom up manner

    workable = []

    for combo in product(rot, repeat = numBoxes):
        if len(set(b.boxNo for b in combo)) != numBoxes:
            continue

        canwork = True

        for a, b in zip(combo[:-1], combo[1:]):
            if a < b :
                canwork = False

        if canwork:
            workable.append(combo)
        
    return max(sum(box.h for box in combo) for combo in workable)

arr = [Box(4,5,2),Box(3,1,6),Box(3,2,1),Box(6,8,3)]
n = len(arr)
print("The maximum possible height of stack is",maxStackHeight(arr, n))
```

Comment: thanks alot , why write number 4 ,  repeat = 4)   , not working if the input is 2 boxes,

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, didn't take this into consideration! I've edited some changes to take into account the number of boxes!

Comment: I'm slightly confused about what you mean?

Comment: your solution is hard .i want 2 simple loop    
     used=[]
    for i in range(1,n):
        for j in range(0,i):
            if (rot[i].w <= rot[j].w and rot[i].l <= rot[j].l) and rot[i].boxNo != rot[j].boxNo:
                if rot[j].boxNo in used and rot[i].boxNo in used:
                        msh[i] = rot[j].h + rot[i].h
                        used.append(rot[i].boxNo)
                        used.append(rot[j].boxNo)
                elif msh[i] < msh[j] + rot[i].h:
                        msh[i] +=   rot[i].h
                        used.append(rot[i].boxNo)

Comment: I couldn't get that solution to work hence why I answered with a working solution for you to try. If you want the original code then I'm sorry but I can't help you :)

Comment: big-o is n^2?  , the solution is brute force?

Comment: what the the big-o of your solution )  @snailor

Comment: Yes I believe it is O(n^2). It is a brute force algorithm, finding all possible combinations of rotations that fit the criteria, and then finds the best one by height using the max function.